# Zero initialiser for biases using get_variable in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, initialization, tensorflow, bias-neuron, zero-initialization

A code I'm modifying is using `tf.get_variable` for weight variables, and `tf.Variable` for bias initialisation. After some searching, it seems that `get_variable` should always be favoured due to its portability in regards to sharing. So I tried to change the bias variable to `get_variable` but can't seem to get it to work.

Original: `tf.Variable(tf.zeros([128]), trainable=True, name="b1")`

My attempt: `tf.get_variable(name="b1", shape=[128], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(shape=[128]))`

I get an error saying that the shape should not be specified for constants. But removing the shape then throws an error for no arguments.

I'm very new to `tf` so I'm probably misunderstanding something fundamental here. Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: `tf.get_variable(name="b1", initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(shape=[128]))` like this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Following should work:
`tf.get_variable(name="b1", shape=[128], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())`

Comment: instead of zero_initializer() can I use a numpy array with values inside?